# How to use DryIoc for constructor injection in Windows Phone 8 PhoneApplicationPage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dependency-injection, dryioc

I tried constructor injection this way:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly ISomeService service;

    public MainPage(ISomeService service)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

In the `App.xaml.cs` constructor:

```cs
public App()
{
    // Global handler for uncaught exceptions.
    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

    DependencyService.Initialize(GetAssemblyFilePathCollection());

    DependencyService
        .Container
        .Register(typeof(MainPage), made: Made.Of(() => new MainPage(Arg.Of<ISomeService>())));

    // The remaining part is omitted.
}
```

`DependencyService` is my custom static class that creates the `Container` and loads the bindings from all the assemblies.

In this case `App.RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)` method is always executed:

- `e.Exception` is a `System.MissingMethodException` with the message `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`
- `e.Uri` is `/MainPage.xaml` as declared in `WMAppManifest.xml` file as `NavigationPage`.

Inside the `MainPage` constructor I can resolve the service successfully using the container directly but I want to use constructor injection.

I have not found any specific example for this. Anybody any idea how does it work?

Comment: Did you register `ISomeService` dependency?

Comment: Yes and inside `MainPage` ctor I can resolve the `ISomeService` dependency successfully using the `Container` directly: `ISomeService service = DependencyService.Container.Resolve<ISomeService>();` works well.

Comment: How can I tell the WP navigation framework to use the container to resolve dependencies automatically? Maybe I missed some configuration.

Comment: The problem is that original exception is masked by infrastructure callback. Dumb question then, does MainPage have a paramerless ctor? Also did you try `made: FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments`?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help with WinPhone specifics :(. Btw, are you using some Mvvm integration package, like Prism.DryIoc.Forms?

Comment: I tried two scenarios: 1) one and only parameterless ctor for MainPage + resolve dependency inside the ctor; 2) one and only ctor with the resolvable dependency; Only the 1st scenario worked.

Comment: Currently I don't use any mvvm integration package. Earlier I used `GalaSoft.MvvmLight` package but I could not use ctor injection with that package. My app is not a Xamarin.Forms app but a standard WP8 Silverlight app.

Comment: This is not related to dependency resolution at all. The XAML infrastructure wants the object to have a parameterless constructor, and there is no way to tell it to use a custom instantiation logic. As a hack, you could use property injection and then `InjectPropertiesAndFields` in your `Loaded` event, but I wouldn't recommend it: you shouldn't mix UI and application logic. Your UI components shouldn't have dependencies.